# Take in variable, instead of direct file path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, file, binary

I'm not sure how to ask this question actually...

REF: http://qif.codeplex.com/

This API takes in the path of a file, can I have it take in a variable instead? binary of the file or string content of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but there is an overload of `ImportFile` that takes a `StreamReader`, so you can do something like that:

- If you have the content as a byte array:

  ```
  byte[] contentBytes = ...
  QifDom qifDom;
  using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(contentBytes))
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
      qifDom = QifDom.ImportFile();
  }
  ```
- If you have the content as a string:

  ```
  string content = ...
  byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
  QifDom qifDom;
  using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(contentBytes))
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
  {
      qifDom = QifDom.ImportFile();
  }
  ```

(Bad API design, by the way... the parameter should have been `TextReader`, not `StreamReader`, so we could have used a `StringReader` rather than converting the string to bytes)

Also, note that the example on the home page is incorrect (there is no `QifDom.Import` property)

Comment: which one is best, binary or string input?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicken_Interchange_Format http://web.intuit.com/support/quicken/docs/d_qif.html (according to the QIF specification, no special characters are used)